# Getting a checkbox to be checked in php

Tags: php

I'm trying to list all the frames and only have those that is connected to the banners table to be checked.
But what I'm getting is only the frames that is connected to the banner instead of all the frames.
I have a many to many relationship with a pivot table.
So my tables look like this

banners table

```
id  |   title
1   |   Home banner
```

frames table

```
id  |   title   |   description |   image
1   |   Frame 1 |   Frame 1     |   frame.jpg
2   |   Frame 2 |   Frame 2     |   frame2.jpg
3   |   Frame 3 |   Frame 3     |   frame3.jpg
4   |   Frame 4 |   Frame 4     |   frame4.jpg
5   |   Frame 5 |   Frame 5     |   frame5.jpg
```

banner_frame table

```
id  |   banner_id   |   frame_id
1   |       1       |       1
2   |       2       |       1
2   |       2       |       5
```

Here is my code

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['b_id']))
    {
        $banner_id = $_GET['b_id'];
    }

    $query = "SELECT frames.id as frameId, frames.title as frameTitle ";
    $query .= "FROM frames ";
    $query .= "INNER JOIN banner_frame ON banner_frame.frame_id = frames.id ";
    $query .= "INNER JOIN banners ON banners.id = banner_frame.banner_id ";
    $query .= "WHERE banner_frame.banner_id = $banner_id ";


    $banner_frame = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    confirmQuery($banner_frame);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($banner_frame))
    {
        $frame_id = $row['frameId'];
        $frame_title = $row['frameTitle'];

        if($frame_id)
        {
            $checked = 'checked';
        }else{
            $checked = '';
        }

        echo "<div class='form-check'>";
        echo    "<input type='checkbox' name='frames[]' id='frame_checkbox' value='$frame_id' $checked> ";
        echo    "<label for='frame_checkbox'>";
        echo        $frame_title;
        echo    "</label>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens bacause you add `where` clause and therefore select data that applied **only** to certain banner.

I suppose you should do something like this (I omit non-relevant code with `....` ):

```
$query = "SELECT frames.id as frameId, frames.title as frameTitle, banners.id as banner_id ";
$query .= "FROM frames ";
$query .= "INNER JOIN banner_frame ON banner_frame.frame_id = frames.id ";
$query .= "INNER JOIN banners ON banners.id = banner_frame.banner_id";

// ....
// Next in while loop you compare current `banner_id` with `$banner_id` variable

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($banner_frame))
{
    // ....
    $checked = '';
    if ($row['banner_id'] == $banner_id) {
         $checked = 'checked';
    }
    // output row data ....
}
```

Comment: That kind of worked, but I'm getting duplicates. For example I'm getting `Frame 1, Frame 1, Frame 2, Frame 2`. Instead of `Frame 1, Frame 2, Frame 3`

Comment: This hapens because banner is used is several frames, you can sort your data by frame_id and output new frame if frame id of new frame is __not equal__ to id of previous frame.